# как указать компаратор std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Хотел создать переменную типа `map<string, vector<string>>`, но чтобы пары в словаре хранились не по возрастанию, а в порядке добавления в словарь. Полагаю, для этого нужно при создании указать компаратор или написать свой. Только как это сделать для map я не нашел, а копаясь в коде map ничего не понял. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Ternvein, если в порядке добавления, то нужен `std::list<std::pair<>>`. В хэш таблице они будут как раз в беспорядке, на что нам намекает слово unordered

Comment: По поводу `std::list<std::pair<> >` - тоже не очень хорошая замена map.
Нужен пример того, чего OP хочет добиться.

Comment: Основное назначение `std::map` - поиск по ключу (ассоциативный массив). Если у вас порядок будет определяться порядком добавления, то что и по чему вы собрались искать потом? Если вы не собираетесь искать, то и `std::map` вам ни к чему.

Comment: Создать хочу переменную в которой хранится : Остановка -> список автобусов проходящих через нее. Нужно проерять наличие остановки в словаре, добавлять автобусы к остановке и возвращаться список автобусов. Просто в последствии поиск будет осуществляться не по номеру добавления а по ключу.

Comment: @Алексей, а зачем вам тогда "в порядке добавления"?

Comment: @Ternvein есть функция которая должна выдавать список всех остановок и их автобусов. И в ней остановки должны выдаваться в том порядке в котором были созданы

Comment: @Алексей, судя по всему у вас типичная проблема стро**к**отипизированных программ. Создайте класс `BusStop`, в котором храните `std::vector<Bus*>`. И эти остановки храните тоже в векторе. И все проблемы уйдут

Comment: @Алексей, тогда вам проще хранить в объекте "остановка" либо инкрементируемый ID, либо дату/время добавления. В зависимости от того, что вам нужно.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb получается лучше создать вектор пар из строки в вектор строк? я тоже об этом думал но тогда поиск будет осуществлять сложнее

Comment: @Алексей, лучше создать классы. Что по-вашему нагляднее `map<string, vector<string>>` или `vector<BusStop>`? А что касается вопроса, всегда можно написать обертку для `list<pair>`, чтобы она вела себя как `map`

Comment: @Алексей, Если вы вдруг не знаете как эту сделать, можете задать другой вопрос, вроде "У меня есть то-то и то-то, как лучше это разбить на классы?" Не уверен, правда, что этому вопросу не налепят минусов, но не в репутации же счастье :)

Comment: @yrhetatejlb, Спасибо большое

Comment: Может вам нужен `std::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BusStop
{
public:
    BusStop()
    {}
    BusStop(BusStop & new_bus)
    {
        this->data = new_bus.data;
    }
    vector<string> & operator[] (string stop)
    {
        for (auto &i : data)
        {
            if (i.first == stop)
                return i.second;
        }
        pair <string, vector <string>> d{ stop, {} };
        data.push_back(d);
        return data.back().second;
    }

    const vector<string> & at(string stop) const 
    {
        for (auto &i : data)
        {
            if (i.first == stop)
                return i.second;
        }
        throw runtime_error("element not found!");
    }
    int count(string stop) const
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (auto &i : data)
        {
            if (i.first == stop) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    size_t size() const 
    {
        return data.size();
    }
    auto begin() const 
    {
        return data.begin();
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return data.end();
    }
    vector<pair<string, vector<string>>> data;
};
```

В результате сделал вот такой класс. 
Для того чтобы итерироваться по объекту класса определили begin() end().
остальное переопределил как в map.
Стало работать как и задумывалось.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

class Custom
{
   public:
    Custom() : key(0) {}
    Custom (int key, const string &data) : key (key), data (data) {} 
    bool operator() (int aKey, int bKey)
    {
        return aKey <  bKey;   //change to '>' for revert sord direction
    }
   private:
    int key;
    string data;
};    


int main()
{

    map<int, string, Custom> m { {2,"bbb"},  {3,"ccc"},  {1,"aaa"} };

    for (const auto &el : m)
        cout<< el.first << " " <<el.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Мутный компаратор. Зачем ему поля, если они не используются в `operator()`? Плюс на `operator()` забыт `const`...